# Parameter passed to pthread changes

Tags: c++, c

i don't know why parameters passed to pthread changes automatically. 
i'll show you my code

the debug  result is this  :

```
begin of while while() =begin= 0 ===
params: a84a5310
->socket: a84a4e70
->connection: a84a52d0(4)
->webserver: a84a4ea0(0)
===== begin of while while() =end====

===== end of while() =begin= 1709692672 ===
params: a84a5310
->socket: a84a4e70
->connection: a84a52d0(4)
->webserver: a84a4ea0(0)
===== end of while() =end====
Accepting...

===== in thread() =begin= 1709692672 ===
params: aacf4240//wrong expected a84a5310
->socket: a84a5310 //wrong expected a84a4e70
->connection: a84a4ea0(0)//wrong expected a84a52d0(4)
->webserver: 65e7d700(0) //wrong expected a84a4ea0(0)
===== in thread() =end====
```

this is struct that i pass to the thread :

```
typedef struct  InfoServer{
   ServerTCP* server;
   WebServer* webserver;
   ConnServer* serverConn;
}ServerInfo;
```

this is debug function :

```
void* show_params(ServerInfo* params, char* where, int n) {

   printf("===== %s =begin= %d ===\n",where, n); 

   printf("params: %x\n", 
           params);
   printf("->socket: %x\n", 
           params->server);
   printf("->connection: %x(%d)\n", 
           params->serverConn, params->serverConn->getConn());
   printf("->webserver: %x(%d)\n", 
           params->webserver);
   printf("===== %s =end====\n",where); 

   fflush(stdout);

}
```

this is main function :

```
void *manageConnection(void *serverConn);
void fineRichiesta(ServerInfo * serverinformation);

int main (int argc , char* argv[]){
   if(argc!=2){
       printf("USAGE: %S , PORT  \n",argv[0]);
   fflush(stdout);
       exit(1);
   }

   int port = atoi(argv[1]);

   ServerTCP* tserver= new ServerTCP(port);
   WebServer* webserv= new WebServer();


   bool exit = false;
   while( true ){

       pthread_t manageConnection_thread;
       ConnServer* serverC=  tserver->acceptConn();
       ServerInfo* serverinfo = (ServerInfo*) malloc(sizeof(ServerInfo));
       serverinfo->server = tserver;
       serverinfo->webserver = webserv;
       serverinfo->serverConn =serverC;


       show_params(serverinfo,"starting in while()",0);

       if(pthread_create(&manageConnection_thread, 
               NULL,
               manageConnection, 
               (void*) &serverinfo)) {
                           error("Error Creating server");
           }
       show_params(serverinfo,"end of while()", manageConnection_thread);

   }
   delete( tserver);
   delete( webserv);
   return 0;
}
```

here is thread code :

```
void *manageConnection(void * serverinformation){
       ServerInfo *serverinfo = (ServerInfo*)serverinformation;
   show_params(serverinfo,"in thread()", pthread_self());

       ConnServer * srvConn = serverinfo->serverConn;
       char* answ;
       if(srvConn){
            answ = (char*)srvConn->riceviServer();
       }

       else    {
       printf("im in else\n");
       fflush(stdout);
       }

       if(!answ){
       printf("finerichiesta\n");
       fflush(stdout);

       fineRichiesta(serverinfo);
       }
       printf("answ: %s\n", answ);
   fflush(stdout);
       char* file = serverinfo->webserver->getFile(answ);
       srvConn->inviaServer(file);     
       fineRichiesta( serverinfo);
       free(answ);
   return NULL;
}
```

function :

```
void fineRichiesta(ServerInfo * serverinformation){
   printf("im in fine richiesta\n");
       fflush(stdout);
   serverinformation->server->disconnect(serverinformation->serverConn);
   free(serverinformation);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Any help would be amazing , im getting crazy -
i dont know if my question is best formulated -

thanks in advance ...

Comment: Change `(void *) &serverInfo` to `(void *) serverInfo`. You want to pass a pointer to the allocated `ServerInfo` to the thread, not a pointer to the `serverInfo` variable!

Comment: @IanAbbott OMG , it's working now , thank u very much ... Lost 4 hours with it , how do I accept you answer ? 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `pthread_create` call is passing the wrong `void *` value to the thread start routine `manageConnection`.

It is passing the address of the `serverInfo` variable:

```
pthread_create(&manageConnection_thread, 
               NULL,
               manageConnection, 
               (void*) &serverinfo)
```

It *should* be passing *value* of the `serverInfo` variable, which points to a filled in `ServerInfo`:

```
pthread_create(&manageConnection_thread, 
               NULL,
               manageConnection, 
               (void*) serverinfo)  // <-- note: ampersand removed here
```